# How many years between Vashti and Esther?

Tags: megillat-esther

The Midrash [Esther R. 3:15] says:

> Rabbi Yoḥanan said: All the years from the time when Vashti was killed till Esther became queen, the wrath of Ahashverosh did not subside…  When did it subside?  When Haman was hanged.

(Because Haman, who was none other than Memucan, [Meg. 12b] had ordered Vashti’s death and the king was mourning for her.]

How many years was the king without a queen?

Comment: [In case anyone is wondering what I wondered, the full midrash explains that when Ester was made queen, his anger abated but was not forgotten. It was forgotten when Haman was hanged.]

Comment: The verse in Esther says explicitly that the party was in year three בשנת שלוש למלכו and Esther was taken in year seven בשנת שבע למלכותו

Comment: @DoubleAA -- thanks, this answers my question.